# Changing the style of a leaflet cluster when pressing it

Tags: css, d3.js, leaflet

I have created a map with clusters created like so:

```
//create clustering markers
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
    singleMarkerMode: true,          //makes sure that single incidents looks the same as clusters (but are still treated as single markers)
    iconCreateFunction: defineClusterIcon 
});

var layer_group = L.geoJSON(geoJson);


markers.addLayer(layer_group);
map.addLayer(markers);
map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

In the defineClusterIcon function, I create a SVG which then is converted to HTML and defines the icon:

```
return L.divIcon({ 
    iconSize: new L.Point(40, 45),
    html: html,
    classname: 'leaflet-div-icon'
});
```

I now want to be able to change the style of the cluster (or marker, which also is styled as a cluster), when pressing it - and I want it to return to the original styling when pressed again.

Instead of changing the style of the actual svg elements, I am thinking that it might be easier to just change the style of the class:

```
.leaflet-div-icon {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: none;       
}
```

Where I then want to have a border when the cluster/marker has been pressed. I do not know, whether it is possible to change the class within the on `clusterclick` or `click` functions, or if it can be done in another way.

My code, as it is now can be found here - where the wanted effect also can be seen on the controls on the right side: http://bl.ocks.org/skov94/f006cd45d2daa2bc67e4f514774fdd0d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of switching the `outline` property of the `leaflet-interactive` div, i would toggle a class as you did with the controls on the right side (say a `outlined` class).

This class toggling has to be done in a "onclick" event handler. Leaflet clustering provide its own cluster click events (`clusterclick`).

The possible targets of the `clusterclick` event seem to be either the text, circle, or svg nodes of the cluster. We want to get the enclosing `div` with class `leaflet-interactive` to add or remove the `outlined` class on it. This will be made easily possible with [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

### Javascript file

```
markers
[...]
.on('clusterclick',function(c) {

  console.log("pressed");
  map.closePopup();

  c.originalEvent.target.closest(".leaflet-interactive")
   .classList.toggle("outlined");

});
```

Then, simply change the style of its `circle` descendants with css:

### CSS file

```
.leaflet-interactive.outlined circle {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

**Edit**: If you're not familiar with css, the selector means: `circle` nodes that are descendants of nodes with classes `leaflet-interactive` AND `outlined`.

Comment: But my problem is that I do not understand how to toggle between classes, when the class is stated in L.divIcon :)

Comment: You can simply add a click event handler afterwards. I've edited my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Okay, it seems that i never enter the on click function, so let me just see if I fully understand: In my css file I create .leaflet-interactive and .leaflet-interactive.outlined circle. In the defineClusterIcon function I return a  L.divIcon with the class 'leaflet-interactive' and outside the function, I then do the d3.selectAll(... ?

Comment: I've edited with extra information. Hope it will be clearer :)

Comment: It seems very clear, but I just can't get it to work - I would be extremely grateful, if maybe you could tell me what I am doing wrong; http://bl.ocks.org/Skov94/f006cd45d2daa2bc67e4f514774fdd0d

Comment: My bad, the event handler we have added seems to be overwritten by Leaflet cluster events. I fixed this by moving the logic inside the `clusterclick` event handling that was already present (where the `console.log` is). I hope it will be ok now, I still don't know how to edit a bl.ocks.org to try it myself...

Comment: Glad I could help :)